# Lodash Two Arrays Replace Values

Tags: arrays, replace, lodash

I am trying to use `lodash` to replace the value in one array object from another array object when a common value matches.

```
array1 = [{
  "internalid": "1233",
  "entity": "1141",
  "items": [{
    "lineuniquekey": "20000",
    "item": "118",
    "drate": "33.75"
  }, {
    "lineuniquekey": "43964",
    "item": "122",
    "drate": "33.75"
  }, {
    "lineuniquekey": "43974",
    "item": "106",
    "drate": "0.00"
  }]
}]

array1 = [{
  "internalid": "1",
  "iname": "SW-CAL-1",
  "item": "106",
  "srate": "30.00"
}];
```

For example, if "item" in array1 matches "item" in array2 then update "drate" in array1 with "srate" from array2.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035090/i-have-two-arrays-how-do-i-find-matchings-elements-and-perform-some-action-lo) but it doesn't really replace the value in the first array from a value of a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Map of `item` -> `srate` from `array2`. Iterate `array1` (the entities) with `Array.map()`. Grab the `items` array from the `entity`, and map the items. For each item check if it exists in the Map. If it does, replace it's `drate` with the value from the Map. If not return the original item:

```js
const array1 = [{"internalid":"1233","entity":"1141","items":[{"lineuniquekey":"20000","item":"118","drate":"33.75"},{"lineuniquekey":"43964","item":"122","drate":"33.75"},{"lineuniquekey":"43974","item":"106","drate":"0.00"}]}]
const array2 = [{"internalid":"1","iname":"SW-CAL-1","item":"106","srate":"30.00"}]

const arr2Map = new Map(array2.map(o => [o.item, o.srate]))

const mapEntityItems = ({ items, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  items: items.map(o => arr2Map.has(o.item) ? ({ 
    ...o,
    drate: arr2Map.get(o.item) 
  }) : o)
})

const result = array1.map(mapEntityItems)

console.log(result)
```